# Issue when dropping an image in Ck-Editor content with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

I am using `ck-editor 4.6.2` for a CMS.

I have a list of images into a pane (gray part of the image) and I want to drag and drop it into my ck-editor content (yellow part).

[image: Drag an image from gray to yellow]

This work perfectly on Chrome / Firefox but it doesn't on Safari. On Safari, the drop occurs but no content is copied.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.inline-editable').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    $('.inline-editable').each(function(index, elt) {
        var editorId = $(elt).attr('id');
        CKEDITOR.inline(editorId, {
            on: {
                drop: function (event) {

                    // I can see the alert, 
                    // so the drop occurs but it doesn't copy any content
                    alert('DROP');


                    // Without this : I only get the url as text in the editor
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I don't understand why Safari doesn't "drop" the HTML code of my image like Chrome/Firefox.

Is there a bug somewhere or did I forget an option to enable this?

Any idea that can help to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you play with the `pasteFilter` setting ?http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFilter

Comment: Thanks to point out this setting. I have tried ti set it to `config.pasteFilter = null;` but unfortunately without any progress

Comment: However if I set `config.pasteFilter = 'plain-text';` I don't have any more content dropped on Chrome